# Extract numbers from string in Google BigQuery using regex

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I'm wondering if i can use regex in BigQuery to extract all the numbers from a string.

I think the below works but just returns first hit - is there a way to extract all the hits.

My use case here is that i basically want to get the biggest number from a url as that tends to be more like a post_id that i need to join on.

here is an example of what i am talking about:

```
SELECT
  mystr,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(mystr, r'(\d+)') AS nums
FROM
  (SELECT 'this is a string with some 666 numbers 999 in it 333' AS mystr),
  (SELECT 'just one number 123 in this one ' AS mystr),
  (SELECT '99' AS mystr),
  (SELECT 'another -2 example 99' AS mystr),
  (SELECT 'another-8766 example 99' AS mystr),
  (SELECT 'http://somedomain.com/2015/12/this-is-a-post-with-id-in-url-99999' AS mystr),
  (SELECT 'http://somedomain.com/2015/12/this-is-a-post-with-id-in-url-99999/gallery/001' AS mystr),
  (SELECT 'http://somedomain.com/2015/12/this-is-a-post-with-id-in-url-99999/print-preview' AS mystr)
```

Results i get from this are:

```
[
  {
    "mystr": "this is a string with some 666 numbers 999 in it 333",
    "nums": "666"
  },
  {
    "mystr": "just one number 123 in this one ",
    "nums": "123"
  },
  {
    "mystr": "99",
    "nums": "99"
  },
  {
    "mystr": "another -2 example 99",
    "nums": "2"
  },
  {
    "mystr": "another-8766 example 99",
    "nums": "8766"
  },
  {
    "mystr": "http://somedomain.com/2015/12/this-is-a-post-with-id-in-url-99999",
    "nums": "2015"
  },
  {
    "mystr": "http://somedomain.com/2015/12/this-is-a-post-with-id-in-url-99999/gallery/001",
    "nums": "2015"
  },
  {
    "mystr": "http://somedomain.com/2015/12/this-is-a-post-with-id-in-url-99999/print-preview",
    "nums": "2015"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a bit of digging, I ended up with this solution:

```
SELECT
  mystr,
  GROUP_CONCAT(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(mystr, r'[^\d]+', ','))) AS nums
FROM
  (SELECT 'this is a string with some 666 numbers 999 in it 333' AS mystr),
  (SELECT 'just one number 123 in this one ' AS mystr),
  (SELECT '99' AS mystr),
  (SELECT 'another -2 example 99' AS mystr),
  (SELECT 'another-8766 example 99' AS mystr),
  (SELECT 'http://somedomain.com/2015/12/this-is-a-post-with-id-in-url-99999' AS mystr),
  (SELECT 'http://somedomain.com/2015/12/this-is-a-post-with-id-in-url-99999/gallery/001' AS mystr),
  (SELECT 'http://somedomain.com/2015/12/this-is-a-post-with-id-in-url-99999/print-preview' AS mystr)
```

[image]

How it works:

- I first use regex to match any **non** number and replace by a comma
- Then use `split` to get the results, empty results are discarded
- `group_concat` is just here to show the results

Comment: Notice that it fails for floats or negative numbers ;), but it can be improved easily.

Answer (score 1):

While you will be using Regex in BigQuery more and more you will realize that its implementation is quite limited as of now
[BigQuery Regular expression functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#regularexpressionfunctions)
[re2 Syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt)

So most likely soon you will have to do something like below
Please note - for your current specific example - below code has absolutely no benefits vs simple solution provided by @Cybril
This solution is more for your potential needs in near future
It uses javascript UDF thus giving you power of javascript regexp implementation
[BigQuery User-Defined Functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions)

```
SELECT mystr, MAX(number) as max_number FROM JS(
  // input table
  (SELECT mystr FROM
    (SELECT 'this is a string with some 666 numbers 999 in it 333' AS mystr),
    (SELECT 'just one number 123 in this one ' AS mystr),
    (SELECT '99' AS mystr),
    (SELECT 'another -2 example 99' AS mystr),
    (SELECT 'another-8766 example 99' AS mystr),
    (SELECT 'http://somedomain.com/2015/12/this-is-a-post-with-id-in-url-99999' AS mystr),
    (SELECT 'http://somedomain.com/2015/12/this-is-a-post-with-id-in-url-99999/gallery/001' AS mystr),
    (SELECT 'http://somedomain.com/2015/12/this-is-a-post-with-id-in-url-99999/print-preview' AS mystr)
  ) ,
  // input columns
    mystr,
  // output schema
  "[
  {name: 'mystr', type: 'string'},
  {name: 'number', type: 'string'}
  ]",
  // function
  "function(r, emit){
    var numbers = r.mystr.match(/(\d+)/g);
    for (var i=0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
      emit({
        mystr: r.mystr,
        number: numbers[i]
      });
    };  
  }"
)
GROUP BY 1
```

Of course you can also move logic of determining max value inside UDF to eliminate extra grouping

Comment: Thanks - was thinking i may need to go UDF approach but i'm still only learning in that regard. Thanks for sharing. I Think some of the BQ team mentioned they are working on a catalog of functions that they hope to release at some stage so looking forward to that also.